# What is the best way to store data from local eth full node to my DB

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, full-node

I would like to get the blockNumber and blockTimestamp for every new finalized block on ETH mainnet. I want to store this information as each new finalized block comes in. I need this data so that I can correlate it to other data I have for transaction analysis.

This is a similar question asked, [Ethers - get historical block.timestamp in batch mode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101710/ethers-get-historical-block-timestamp-in-batch-mode). And I went down the path of setting up my own ETH full node on an ARM board (as suggested in the comments). Thought that this might be good learning experience so I jumped right in. I am using Geth as the execution client for this node.

I am able to query for the latest finalized block using this RPC curl request

```
curl --data '{"id": 1, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_getBlockByNumber","params": ["finalized", false], "id":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST <my_ip>
```

I see the data that I need, but I want to figure out how to extract this to my own DB every time a finalized block is created. What is the best way to do this? I was hoping I could `geth attach` a script and use a subscription, but it seems like that may not be possible. There are limited subscriptions in geth, and I am not sure how to persist a connection to my DB in the script.

The only way I can think of achieving this is to setup a micro service to poll geth every couple of seconds for the latest finalized block. But that seems very inefficient. Why cant I have my node send information to my DB? Is there a way to get my node to do this?

Any information would be very helpful as I am new to this layer of the BC stack. Thanks!